# How to add additional escape using lxml

Tags: python, xml, escaping, lxml, special-characters

I'm trying to use LXML to process a string in a XML file. The problem is the output file unable to escape some of the special characters(e.g. "\n" and " ' ").

xml.sax.saxutils.escape only escapes &, <, and > by default, but it does provide an entities parameter to additionally escape other strings. Does `lxml` provide the same flexibility in entities parameter for escape?

For XML:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape

def xmlescape(data):
    return escape(data, entities={
        "'": "&apos;",
        "\"": "&quot;"
    })
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about lxml. But you can remove these special characters using replace.

Here is an example:

```
string = "I have a string with special value ' in between." 
print(string.replace("'", ""))
```

output:

```
I have a string with special value  in between.
```

Comment: The replace only appears as python output(using print), not while output as xml file(tree.write).